# Can't invoke 'animationWithDuration' error message for a simple fade out on UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel

I'm trying to make a simple Fade in-out animation on an UILabel in swift but I get an 'can't invoke...' error message.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sendButtonLabel: UILabel?

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
            self.sendButtonLabel?.alpha = 1.0
        })
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Try cleaning your Project, deleting the derrived data, or try casting the duration to double using: Double(1.5)

Comment: I tried all three and this still does not work :/

Comment: compiles just fine here. Can you post more code - the whole class? Likely the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: try setting `animations: { _ in`, maybe the compiler is having an issue with the omitted parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
            self.sendButtonLabel?.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
```